# Validation Rule formula for closed case

Tags: validation-rule

I'm trying to create a validation rule that when a certain case record type is closed if any of the fields listed are blank (they are checkboxes) the rule is fired. The below is not working:

```
AND(
    RecordType.DeveloperName = "Voda Straggler Upgrade",
    ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Closed'),
    OR(
        Checked_tariff_is_correct__c = FALSE,
        Checked_discon_report_again__c = FALSE,
        Checked_tariffs_updated_correctly__c = FALSE,
        Checked_CEDs_updated_correctly__c = FALSE,
        Upgrade_base_updated__c = FALSE
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The Recordtype's developer name never contains spaces. Spaces and non-alphanumeric characters are replaced with an underscore (but there is never more than one underscore between "words").

So you either want

```
RecordType.DeveloperName = "Voda_Straggler_Upgrade",
```

or to use the plain 'ol "Name" field (a.k.a. the Recordtype's Label)

```
RecordType.Name = "Voda Straggler Upgrade",
```

Additionally, you can shorten the `OR()` section a bit. Checkboxes are boolean values behind the scenes, so you don't need to compare them for equality to true/false.

```
Checked_tariff_is_correct__c = FALSE,
```

is exactly the same as

```
NOT(Checked_tariff_is_correct__c),
```

Comment: Thank you that has worked!